# RTL8812AU/21AU Wireless drivers vs. RTL8814AU for Asus AC68, AC1900 wireless adapter on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers

This was my old question but now I'm getting:

```
(base) nyck33@nyck33-ubuntu2304:~/rtl8814au$ sudo make dkms_install
[sudo] password for nyck33: 
mkdir -p /usr/src/8814au-5.8.5.1
cp -r * /usr/src/8814au-5.8.5.1
dkms add -m 8814au -v 5.8.5.1
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/usr/src/8814au-5.8.5.1/dkms.conf)
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/8814au/5.8.5.1/source -> /usr/src/8814au-5.8.5.1
dkms build -m 8814au -v 5.8.5.1
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/8814au/5.8.5.1/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j12 KVER=6.2.0-34-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-34-generic/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for 8814au: 5.8.5.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8814au/5.8.5.1/build/make.log for more information.
make: *** [Makefile:2410: dkms_install] Error 10
```

Since my Ubuntu version is much higher, I thought I'd ask again how to get this Asus Wifi adapter working.  Asus AC68 AC1900.

Comment: What's your `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`?

Comment: Your "8814au" source package is not compatible with kernel 6.2. I guess it is not needed with kernel 6.2. Try a newer source. This seems compatible with 6.2: https://github.com/morrownr/8814au